# Machine Learning on Sequential Data Reperesenting Events

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, recurrent-neural-network, point-process, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Would you please recommend which model should I use for modeling user activity observing certain events that happen to them in time. I want to make sense of the history of events (just a presence of something in history as well as continuous change of some measurements), the fact that a certain sets of events are present in user's history (possibly, in a given period of time).

Event is something that can be either measured (continuous) (for example, height, weight, age) or binary (gym sign up, visiting a class).

Instead of doing feature engineering and working on time transformation, I hope to use data as is. I might loose some valuable information through that feature engineering, as it's limiting actual data with ad-hoc metrics.

So, what family of machine learning models would I use to predict, for example, time to weight loss or categorize a patient into a predefined set of labels.

Sorry, could not come up with better example, but there are many applications for this, I cannot disclose mine. It is not something like image or text data, but actual user-level data, with not as many events, timestamps, and they are not measured on the regular basis - gaps in time are large and irregular.

Comment: I would look into Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs) - the question is pretty vague about the specific data you have on user but RNNs architectures are very flexible and you can adopt a lot of information into them including information gaps